# Play framework ignoring external application.conf

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have a Java application (written with Play 2.2.1) and I need to automate it's deployment. I usually did that by using a `play dist` command, which generates a zip file, which I later extract to a deployment folder along with the `conf` folder, and just run a custom start script. That script just calls the generated `start` script with some standard command line parameters for https configuration, namely:

`./start -Dhttps.port=<port> -Dhttps.keyStoreType=<type> -Dhttps.keyStore=<file> -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=<password>`

Now I need to deploy this to different environments, which means that I need to have a central place for configuration files (same location, but different files, for all environments) and keep the same start script. I tried doing it with the `-Dconfig.file=<absolute path to application.conf file>` parameter, but as far as I could tell, it ignores that custom application.conf. The application.conf in question just contains the parameters that I used via command line. It is ignored even if I put the conf folder to a deployment directory, so it seems that it always loads some kind of a default configuration.

I am aware of a different solution with the nginx or similar, where I would just proxy the requests to my original Play application, or with custom run scripts for different environments, but I want to know what exactly is wrong with this approach and why it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Curious, try to use name other than `application.conf` for this additional file

Comment: @biesior already tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem :/

Comment: @ms. Did you manage to find a solution to this problem? I am also facing the same problem. After `sbt dist`, and unzip, I run `bin/myapp -Dconfig.file=/path/to/conf/application.prod.conf`.  I get error `Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[Slick error : jdbc driver not defined in application.conf for db.default.driver key]`. It works without any problem if I edit the conf file inside the default jar.

Comment: @tuxdna unfortunately, no. I ended up using a custom configuration framework (developed in-house) and supplying all the play2 parameters via command-line.

Comment: I think I would also take the same path :-)